What was the first "Star Trek" style teleporter in SF?
What was the first work of fiction to use a teleport device similar to the transporters in Star Trek? Or did Gene Roddenberry invent the concept?
To count it must match the following:

It must be a technological device, not transported by  magic, psychic power, or a natural wormhole.

It must have been designed as a transporter, not an unexpected result of a fault in the device.

It must not require a receiving station. In Trek, you can beam from the ship to a remote planet. It doesn't require a transporter to be on the planet.  So, for example, The Fly wouldn't count.  In that film the device sent objects from one booth to another booth.


Any media, could be prose, comic, radio,  movie, or anything else.

In Fred T. Jane's 1897 novel To Venus in Five Seconds the Venusians have some ridiculously fast means of interplanetary travel but I don't think it's anything like a Star Trek transporter. I could be wrong.

Does it have to have 2-way capacity?  Star Trek transporters can, of course, also transport somebody from a remote planet back to the ship as well.  Some others might only allow this in one direction.

Gene Roddenberry didn't invent the concept of being teleported through space by technology.   Richard G. Van Treuren in "On Ship to Surface Transportation", the Best of Trek # 2, page 56, mentions that science fiction already had many "world without distance" concepts, "..from the comic book Magnus: Robot Fighter to Heinlein's Tunnel in the Sky..."  I can add the teleport devices in A. E. Van Vogt's Mission to the Stars (1943-45, 1955), for example.  The main character in The Radio Man by Ralph Milne Farley (1924, 1948) is transmitted to Venus.

Thank you, I'm aware that Star Trek wasn't the first teleport device, but many of the preceding ones  used a sending booth and a receiving booth.

You mean the style which registers your structure, kills you, and creates a copy of you elsewhere?

1928: "The Voyage to Kemptonia", a short story by E. M. Scott in Amazing Stories, October 1928, available at the Internet Archive.
The mad scientist has discovered a second moon of Earth:

"By means of many observations, I have gathered much information regarding this satellite, which, exercising the time-honored rights of discovery, I have named Kemptonia, in honor of myself, as its discoverer.
"I find that Kemptonia revolves around the earth, in a regular orbit and is about thirty miles distant from our globe. This little follower of the earth travels through space at the rate of about three miles per minute, requiring approximately six twenty-four-hour days to complete its orbit. [sic!]

Prof. Kempton has also invented a matter transmitter with which he hopes to explore his moon, or rather to send a stooge to explore it for him. Of course there is no apparatus at the other end.

"At one time I considered the construction of an airship, with an enclosed car, of sufficient size and power to allow me to visit my planet, as I secretly called my discovery, but I abandoned this idea as being impractical.
[. . . .]
"I will not attempt to explain my discovery to you, in technical terms, but will simply state, that by the joint application of certain electrical rays, in connection with particular chemical reagents and under certain physical conditions, I am enabled to dissolve, transport and re-mold matter.
"In other words, my discoveries permit me to etherealize your body, transport it, as sound is transported by the ordinary radio, reassemble it at a fixed destination, and then return it, by the same means, unharmed, to my laboratory."
[. . . .]
"When I found that I could successfully dissolve and construct, without apparent injury, the bodies of live animals the idea occurred to me that, if I could convey their bodies through space and then re-animate them at a distance, I would, in this way, be able to visit and explore Kemptonia.
"But, Professor Kempton," I interposed, "if you have developed such an instrument, why bother exploring a tiny moon belonging to the earth? Why not investigate some of the great planets?"
"I rather expected some such a question," the professor answered. "I will tell you. In the first place, my present apparatus is entirely too weak to carry my rays to the nearest of the planets. In the second place, although it might be possible to construct a machine powerful enough to convey matter to the distant stars, I desire to transport and recall living, not dead, matter. And no form of life could survive a voyage through the deadly cold of the immense space that separates us from the major planets. But I have transported several animals through the comparatively insignificant distance that separates Kemptonia from the earth. Some of these I have returned, others I have allowed to remain there. I did not care to bring them all back.


Excellent candidates!  Might it not be better as two separate answers, allowing the OP to choose one or the other?

@Basya I wasn't sure which way would be better. I will follow your suggestion and split this into two answers.

An excellent possibility is the "vibra-transmitter" from "Into the Meteorite Orbit" by Frank K. Kelly, published in Amazing Stories, December 1933.

He stood, still in the pajamas he had worn in the prosaic safety of his Chicago bedroom, upon a circular plate of smooth, hard metal, flanked on either side by the banked tubes and massed dials of some strange apparatus, his position directly under the steady glare of a great blue-flaming dome light. Amazement struck him again, and overwhelming curiosity. He stared again at the man in the acid-spotted smock, his eyes taking in the curious costume, half that of the confined sedentary scientist, half that of an outdoor huntsman.
"Where am I?" Girand demanded at last, after a moment of mutual appraisal. [...]


[...] Girand obeyed, and found himself standing on the cool metal floor of a huge room, whose distant roof lost itself in shadowy vagueness high above. The room was crowded, filled almost to capacity by endless rows of apparatus of complexity and uses unguessable.  Granton nodded.
"My laboratory," he said simply. "I suppose you're wondering how you got here. That plate from which you just stepped is the receiving instrument of my vibra-transmitter; I've just finished reintegrating the matter of your body. The beam into which you walked in your bedroom simply reduced your body to vibration which is carried on a returning wave-channel to the plate here... And you came."


My word, that was fast. And a likely candidate.  Upvoted for the moment, will probably Accept later.

@Pete Your question specified "transmitter but no receiver" but this seems to be an instance of "receiver but no transmitter". From your comment I guess this is also acceptable? Good to know as I look for earlier examples. Of course the Star Trek transporter works both ways.

Yeah, either way is fine.  Preferably a device that works either way.

In case the device in my 1928 answer ("The Voyage to Kemptonia" by E. M. Scott) is considered insufficiently Star-Trekky because of its limited range, here is a slightly later example of an interplanetary transporter from a much more famous author:
1930: "The Cosmic Express", a short story by Jack Williamson, first published in Amazing Stories, November 1930, available at the Internet Archive, also at Project Gutenberg.

The sallow youth winked. "And now what can I do for you, Eric?"
"We want to go to Venus, if that ray of yours can put us there."
"To Venus? Impossible. My orders are to use the Express merely between the sixteen designated stations, at New York, San Francisco, Tokio, Lon—"
"See here, Charley," with a cautious glance toward the door, Eric held up the silver flask. "For old time's sake, and for this—"
The boy seemed dazed at sight of the bright flask. Then, with a single swift motion, he snatched it out of Eric's hand, and bent to conceal it below his instrument panel.
"Sure, old boy. I'd send you to heaven for that, if you'd give me the micrometer readings to set the ray with. But I tell you, this is dangerous. I've got a sort of television attachment, for focusing the ray. I can turn that on Venus—I've been amusing myself, watching the life there, already. Terrible place. Savage. I can pick a place on high land to set you down. But I can't be responsible for what happens afterward."
"Simple, primitive life is what we're looking for. And now what do I owe you—"
"Oh, that's all right. Between friends. Provided that stuff's genuine! Walk in and lie down on the crystal block. Hands at your sides. Don't move."
The little door had swung open again, and Eric led Nada through. They stepped into a little cell, completely surrounded with mirrors and vast prisms and lenses and electron tubes. In the center was a slab of transparent crystal, eight feet square and two inches thick, with an intricate mass of machinery below it.
Eric helped Nada to a place on the crystal, lay down at her side.
"I think the Express Ray is focused just at the surface of the crystal, from below," he said. "It dissolves our substance, to be transmitted by the beam. It would look as if we were melting into the crystal."
"Ready," called the youth. "Think I've got it for you. Sort of a high island in the jungle. Nothing bad in sight now. But, I say—how're you coming back? I haven't got time to watch you."
"Go ahead. We aren't coming back."

But at the end they get beamed back:

Suddenly flame lapped up about them, the same white fire they had seen as they lay on the crystal block. Dizziness, insensibility overcame them. A few moments later, they were lying on the transparent table in the Cosmic Express office, with all those great mirrors and prisms and lenses about them.
A bustling, red-faced official appeared through the door in the grill, fairly bubbling apologies.
"So sorry—an accident—inconceivable. I can't see how he got it! We got you back as soon as we could find a focus. I sincerely hope you haven't been injured."
"Why—what—what—"
"Why I happened in, found our operator drunk. I've no idea where he got the stuff. He muttered something about Venus. I consulted the auto-register, and found two more passengers registered here than had been recorded at our other stations. I looked up the duplicate beam coordinates, and found that it had been set on Venus. I got men on the television at once, and we happened to find you.
"I can't imagine how it happened. I've had the fellow locked up, and the 'dry-laws' are on the job. I hope you won't hold us for excessive damages."


There is one plot point in this story that may confuse some of you Gen Alphas and foreigners. The story was written and published in the United States in 1930, i.e., during the Prohibition Era (1920–1933).

"insufficiently Star-Trekky because of its limited range": Generally speaking, the Star Trek transporter also has limited range.  It's primarily to get people to and from orbit.  In early episodes even ship-to-ship was considered risky unless transporting to a receiving transporter.  There are episodes where it was pushed farther, or where an alien's transporter had more range, but the Star Trek transporter's range was limited.  If you could beam to other planets, why build a big ship to get close first?

The question asks:

What was the first work of fiction to use a teleport device similar to the transporters in Star Trek? Or did Gene Roddenberry invent the concept?

Here are some examples of teleportation devices before Star Trek.
Gene Roddenberry didn't invent the concept of being teleported through space by technology. Richard G. Van Treuren in "On Ship to Surface Transportation", The Best of Trek # 2 (1979), page 56, mentions that science fiction already had many "world without distance" concepts..

..from the comic book Magnus: Robot Fighter  to Heinlein's Tunnel in the Sky...

In the first episode of The Outer Limits (1963-1965) "The Galaxy Being" on September 16, 1963, an Earth Scientist makes contact with alien scientist in the Andromeda Galaxy.  And the Alien is accidentally transmitted to Earth.  I am not certain whether devices on both ends are necessary.
The later episode "The Mice" January 6, 1964 also involves matter transportation between worlds.
in Roger Corman's film Not of This Earth (1957) natives of the planet Davanna apparently can teleport themselves to Earth, but I don't remember if they need a receiving device on Earth.
Heinlein's Tunnel in the Sky (1955) features teleportation machines which can send people to distant uninhabited planets, and can bring them back again.  As nearly as I can remember there was no mention of any receivers on the target planet.
A.E. van Vogt's novel The Mixed Men or Mission to the Stars (1952, 1955) is largely a "fix-up" combining several shorter stories originally published in Astounding from September 1943 to January 1945.  Teleportation technology is widely used aboard the mighty Earth space battleship Star Cluster.  15,000 years earlier, a different form of matter transmission was used, probably working somewhat like Star Trek's transporter, since it had the side effect that people who used it were changed physically and mentally.  They were called "Dellian Robots", and were persecuted, until they and their "normal" friends fled from the Milky Way Galaxy to the Large (or Lesser) Magellanic Cloud where they established the 50 Suns civilization.  And now the Star Cluster is exploring the Cloud.
Arthur C. Clarke's short story "Loophole" Astounding Science Fiction April 1946, involved matter transmission from Earth to Mars.  One way until transmitters could be transmitted to Mars for the return trip.
The first episode of the movie serial Flash Gordon's Trip to Mars (1938) features an energy beam from Mars transporting Martians to Earth about 6 minutes in. That episode is available online on youtube so it may be easy to decide whether it fills the requirements in the question.
I have never read the "Radio Man" Series by Ralph Milne Farley (Roger Sherman Hoar) but it involved matter transmission.
In The Radio Man also known as An Earthman on Venus, Argosy All Story Weekly June 28 to July 19, 1924, book publication 1948, the protagonist, brilliant radio engineer Myles Standish Cabot, accidentally invents a matter transmitter and transmits himself to the planet Venus.
In the third book in the series The Radio Planet Miles has returned to Earth, so he must have perfected his invention (and as far as I know it doesn't need a receiver on the other end, but people who read the books would know).  At the beginning he returns to Venus and a lot of plot happens.  It was published in Argosy All Story Weekly June 26 to July 31, 1926, and published as a book in 1964.
And there are later stories in the "Radio" series.
https://www.erbzine.com/mag15/1514.html
So this seems to be earlier than the 1933, 1930, and 1928 stories in other answers.
And it might not be the first teleportation technology in US science fiction.  I wouldn't be surprised if Ray Cummings, for example, had teleportation technology even before The Radio Man.
And then I thought of checking the online The Encyclopedia of Science Fction and it has an article on matter transmission.

Early stories of matter transmission include "The Man Without a Body" (March 1877 The Sun anon) by Edward Page Mitchell and "Professor Vehr's Electrical Experiment" (24 January 1885 The Argonaut) by Robert Duncan Milne, in both of which the process is interrupted with dire consequences; a later variant of the same theme, with an additional horrific twist, is George Langelaan's twice-filmed "The Fly" (June 1957 Playboy) (see The Fly; The Vulture). Matter transmitters feature as a means of interplanetary travel in Fred T Jane's tongue-in-cheek To Venus in Five Seconds (1897) and as a method of ore-shipping in Garrett P Serviss's The Moon Metal (1900), but few other authors could bring themselves to deploy the notion until the advent of the sf Pulp magazines, when it was quickly added to the standard vocabulary of symbols, featuring in such stories as "The Secret of Electrical Transmission" (September 1922 Science and Invention) by Clement Fezandié, The Radio Man (28 June-19 July 1924 Argosy All-Story Weekly; 1948) by Ralph Milne Farley, "The Moon Menace" (September 1927 Weird Tales) by Edmond Hamilton and "The Cosmic Express" (November 1930 Amazing) by Jack Williamson. Matter transmitters are rarely featured in work done outside the genre, although Norman Matson's Doctor Fogg (1929) is an interesting comedy about an unexpected arrival by such means.

https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/matter_transmission
I don't know if this this includes the very first matter transmission story.  And since I haven't read any of the stories before Arthur C. Clarke's "Loophole" (1946), nor seen any of the named productions before Flash Gordon's Trip to Mars (1938) I don't know which of the listed ones was the first to fill the requirements in the question.
